# How to link to a class in a different namespace with doxygen

Tags: python, documentation, doxygen

I'm documenting a Python project with doxygen (1.8.17). I want to reference the documentation for a class from the main page. I define the latter in a comment block with `@mainpage`, that is in **a separate file from the one that defines the class**. When I mention the class name in other parts of the documentation, it is automatically linked. However it is not in this case. I suspect this has to do with the concept of namespace (which is not fully clear to me, and I think it is not exactly the same as in Python). I have tried to *force* the link creation with `@ref ClassName`, but it raises a warning:

```
warning: unable to resolve reference to 'ClassName' for \ref command
```

If I copy the same comment block with the documentation to the file that defines `ClassName`, then it works. But this is not a good solution because I actually want to link to classes that are defined in different files, and I do not want to have the main page scattered through the project.

How can I tell doxygen that this is a class defined elsewhere?

---

As suggested in the comments, I add now a minimal working example:

The module that defines `MyClass` is **test.py**

```
"""! @brief Module test

@date December 2021
"""


class MyClass:
    """! @brief Documentation for this class"""

    pass
```

Now I have a main module **main.py** where I think it makes sense to put the documentation for the main page:

```
"""! @brief Main module

@date December 2021
"""

##
# @mainpage
# ## Introduction
# Here I want to refer to @ref MyClass
```

This is all the project, just 2 files. Now, I run `doxygen` and there is no link and I get the warning I mentioned above:

[image]

Comment: Which version of doxygen ar you using? Please show some code (in your question) that illustrates your problem.